# How to reduce maximum LED brightness

Tags: lighting

First-timer here.

I want to lower the maximum brightness of various LED circuits in my home so that the "public" dimmer switches on the walls, when at maximum, only produce the lumen limit that I, the boss of this house, have chosen.

In other words, I want to install a resistor of sorts that is not going to be messed with by anyone other than me.

I haven't tried anything yet, but my first thought was to install a second dimmer in a nearby closet -- in a junction box, code-compliant and all -- between the public dimmer and the light circuit. Or does it matter which dimmer comes first?

But this can get ridiculous fast. Is there a better way to achieve this?

I don't want to delve quite yet into the world of smart bulbs and hubs and the like. I'm no Luddite, but I have bigger fish to fry right now.

And if my need to control the max brightness sounds odd, it's because a couple of the can circuits brutally overwhelm all the other layers of lighting when fully lit. And I'm the only one who seems to notice or care.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you put lower power bulbs in the offending fixtures? Put a filter on the cans that are too bright?

Comment: Some dimmers have a high and low limit adjust that is accessible when the wall plate is removed.

Comment: Our Lutron dimmers have an adjustment for the low setting, but not for the high.

Comment: Insteon dimmers allow you to set the “local” dim level, which is the normal level the switch turns on to when the switch is tapped.  That level can be over-ridden at the switch tho with more taps or presses.  Although it can be unplugged after programming, that setting does need the hub for setup, basic programming can be achieved without a hub, some settings are only exposed if you have a hub.

Comment: Are the lights that need dimmed on the same circuit as the other lights or are they on different branch circuits.

Answer (score 4):

Put lower power bulbs in the offending fixtures. If you were sneaky about this, you could reduce the power in stages so that the insubordinate bunch you are afflicted with would not notice that the fixture was putting out less light than formerly.

If you wanted to be public about taking charge, you could put a filter on the cans that are too bright. A black wire screen would reduce light output but still allow air flow to keep the lamp at the desired temperature.

Answer (score 1):

### Get a dimmer with a *high-end trim* adjustment

Some high-end dimmers have an adjustment function called "high-end trim" that lets you set an upper limit on the dimming range.  Getting and installing a dimmer with this function (ask at your local lighting or electrical supply house) on the offending circuits would let you adjust the dimming range down for ordinary use, then back up to full power if you need it for a special occasion.